# How to run selenium/junit teste case using maven command line

Tags: selenium, maven, junit, junit4

I'm trying to run an automated test from the command line, but when using the "mvn clean test" command, only the "BUILD SUCCESS" log is displayed, but the browser is not started and the test is not executed.

I'm using: - Junit 4

- Selenium 3.141.59
- Java 8
- Eclipse IDE
  -Maven 3.6.0

Someone can help me ?

I dont know what is happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add maven surefire plugin in your pom or failsafe:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then try again running:

```
mvn clean test
```

All classses containing Test/Tests should be picked up

LOG:

```
[INFO] Running DummyTest
Test was executed
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.024 s - in DummyTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Thank you Alex!
I put that plugin and few others and it did work!
Fo every one that is getting problems to generate the allure-results folder and the json files inside, i suggest to analize the "command line run" with the respective dependency manager.